# RServe share library code

Tags: r, rserve

Is it possible that processes spawned by RServe share some common libraries loaded once into memory?
Imagine that I need to execute bellow code on 100 different RConnections concurrently.

```
library(libraryOfSize40MB)
fun()
```

It means that I need about 3.9GB of memory just to load library. I would prefer to load library once and then execute `fun()` one hundred times, so that I can run this on cheap host.

Maybe this is helpful? 
https://github.com/s-u/Rserve/blob/master/NEWS#L40-L48

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634345/how-to-start-rserve-pre-loaded-with-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You have to run RServe from R shell using `run.serve` preceded by loaded libraries:

```
library(Rserve)

#load libraries so all connections will share them
library("yaml")
library("reshape")
library("rjson")
library("zoo")
(...)
library("stringr")

run.Rserve(debug = TRUE, port = 6311, remote=TRUE, auth=FALSE, args="--no-save", config.file = "/etc/Rserve.conf")
```

Every new connection will be able to see this libraries

```
library(RSclient)
con = RS.connect(host='10.1.2.3')
RS.eval(con, quote(search()))
> #lots of libraries available
```

Comment: For anyone else who thinks this doesn't work, as I initially did, you must execute your commands through the RS.eval method.