# Rserve sub-processes memory issue

Tags: r, memory-management, subprocess, rjava, rserve

I have a Java server from which I am calling R functions using c.eval.
I use Rserve to do this and preload all libraries using the following call

> R CMD Rserver --RS-conf Rserve.conf

The file Rserve.conf has all my loaded libraries. The total memory requirement for this is around 127MB.

The challenge I have is that every time I call a function from within my Java server, a new process is spawned but it looks like the process requires the full 127MB of memory. So with 32GB RAM, roughly, 240 concurrent calls are sufficient to max out the memory usage and brings the server crashing down.

I found this link: [Rserve share library code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433840/rserve-share-library-code) but it talks about exactly what I have been doing. Any help in understanding how to make Rserve work without it loading all libraries for every call would be much appreciated.